# How to replace %20 with - in django urls

Tags: python, django

I have a url which contains `%20`. I want to replace it with `-` with the help of regex

I already tried replace method

```
url(r'^timeanalysis/(?P<name>[\w|\W]+)'.replace('%20','-'), timeseries.timeanalysis, name='timeanalysis')
```

I don't want to change my database.

Comment: This isn't something you would do in the URL pattern. Can you explain more precisely what you are trying to do? Where is this URL coming from, and what do you want the result to be?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/timeanalysis/Big%20Data%20Hadoop ...I want to change this url to this http://localhost:8000/timeanalysis/Big-Data-Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need to fix at the point you generate the link, not in the urlconf.

Usually you would use a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) that is automatically pre-populated from the title/name, replacing spaces with dashes as necessary.